# Prove that $(a+b-c)^2+(b+c-a)^2+(c+a-b)^2>ab+bc+ca$

Tags: inequality

How can I prove $(a+b-c)^2+(b+c-a)^2+(c+a-b)^2>ab+bc+ca$? 
We have

$(a+b-c)^2+=a^2+b^2+b^2+2ab-2bc-2ca$,
$(b+c-a)^2+=b^2+c^2+a^2+2bc-2ca-2ab$
$(c+a-b)^2+=c^2+a^2+b^2+2ca-2ab-2bc$

But I don't know how to show the required result?
Please give hint. Thank you

Comment: what kind of numbers are $a,b,c$?

Comment: $a,b,c\in \mathbb R$

Comment: Just to confirm, the third term of the left hand side should also be squared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$(a+b-c)^2+(b+c-a)^2+(c+a-b)^2 = 3a^2+3b^2+3c^2-2ab-2bc-2ca$$
From AM-GM, we have $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$, $b^2+c^2 \geq 2bc$ and $c^2+a^2 \geq 2ca$. Hence,
$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2) \geq 2(ab+bc+ca) \implies 3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \geq 3ab+3bc+3ca$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
(a+b-c)^2+(b+c-a)^2+(c+a-b)^2 & = 3a^2+3b^2+3c^2-2ab-2bc-2ca\\
& \geq 3ab+3bc+3ca-2ab-2bc-2ca\\
& = ab+bc+ca
\end{align}
which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this inequality is equivalent to $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$ which is
$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0$

Comment: This is algebraically incorrect.

Comment: aha then give me a counter example please

Comment: Why should there be a counterexample?  You have simply omitted a step in your rush to post an answer, as you habitually do.

Comment: ok the inequality above is incorrect, a square is missing

Comment: you said my answer is algebraically incorrect, then must be a mistake i think the given inequality (with square) is equivalent to $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$ and this is the sum of squares

Comment: in the proof above is a mistake since the AM-GM inequality only holds for $a,b,c>0$ or $a,b,c\geq 0$

Comment: The original post likely omits the square term as a typo, but it seems the strict inequality there (in the Question) might be intentional (and deserving of at least a mention in an Answer).

Comment: if $a=b=c$ is hold then we get the equal sign

Comment: All good points that would improve your Answer.